# VBA Run-time error 91

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I assigned a macro to a shape, but I'm receiving a Run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set. But, when I run the Macro from the Developer tab, it works. The "ActiveChart.Axes" line is where the error is coming from. I'm new to VBA so any help would be appreciated. Should I replace "ActiveChart.Axes" with "ActiveSheet.ChartObjects"?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScaleAxes()
 With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("B14").Value
    .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("B15").Value
    .MajorUnit = ActiveSheet.Range("B16").Value
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: maybe there is not an active chart?

Comment: Set the chart to a variable.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line before the `with` statement.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
```

Assuming "chart 1" is the name of your chart.

Comment: I tested and this works. Up voted as this is an odd problem and the solution wasn't obvious.